# how to login using ssh with password?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, openssl

I want to login using ssh and password store in a text file or may be in a varible

I am trying below method but i am getting an error please suggest me correct way.

echo "123456" | ssh root@127.0.0.1

error: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

[image]

Comment: why dont you use key authentification? there in no password needed, in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `sshpass` with below commands.

> wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/sshpass-1.05-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

```
 rpm -ivh sshpass-1.05-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Now login with ssh

> sshpass -p ‘password’ ssh root@IP

Comment: a little bit more secure is to use: `SSHPASS=123456 sshpass -e ssh root@127.0.0.1` this will hide the password using ps...

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would want to use ssh keys instead of a plaintext password stored in a file/script. This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594698/using-a-variables-value-as-password-for-scp-ssh-etc-instead-of-prompting-for